# citrix and keybd_event problem

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, citrix

Is citrix supporting keybd_event, I have a problem that it ignores events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citrix thin clients uses the scancode param of keybd_event even when MS says it is unused and should be 0. You need to supply the physical scancode aswell for the citrix client to get it. Citrix client also has major problem with keyboard input generated with the SendInput API.

Answer (score 0):

Does your keyboard shortcut conflict with a Citrix Hot Key:

[image]

If so try changing in the Citrix Program Neighborhood (Tools>ICA Settings)

Hope this helps...